# MySQL GROUP BY query returns only one row

Tags: php, mysql

```
    $q2 =   "SELECT startdate, 
             GROUP_CONCAT(summary separator '<br />') as summary, 
             GROUP_CONCAT(TIME(startdate)) AS starttime, 
             GROUP_CONCAT(TIME(enddate)) AS endtime
             FROM oc_clndr_objects
             WHERE calendarid = $calID
             GROUP BY DATE(startdate)
             ORDER BY startdate ASC";
```

This above query is only returning one result (3 events for one 1 date as expected) - however there is 1 event that is repeating daily, and the query does not go beyond the first startdate.

I know it has something to do with the GROUP BY clause and something about Aggregation functions but I cannot wrap my head around it. - The output is visible at http://www.deliriousdreams.co.uk/ - "DJ Schedule Test"

Any help with correcting the slightly illegal SQL query would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Alright, groovy people, amended to DATE(startdate) AS startdate. One little niggle, after that I would like to be able to sort them by DATE and then TIME (earliest first) - Obviously both DATE and TIME are derived from the startdate (DATETIME stamp) - is this possible by amending the above query or would I have to do some PHP witchcraft?

Comment: Your `GROUP BY` differs from the `SELECT` list. You would need to use `SELECT DATE(startdate)` to make this work the way you intend.

Comment: try to select  DATE(startdate) instead of startdate

Comment: StartDate could be datetime.  Time could vary per record.  As others have said convert it to a date so it drops the time, the group by should then work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And it is done! This is the solution I was looking for...

```
SELECT
       DATE(startdate) AS startdate, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(summary separator '<br />') as summary, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(TIME(startdate)) AS starttime, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(TIME(enddate)) AS endtime
FROM
       (SELECT * FROM oc_clndr_objects ORDER BY startdate ASC) AS temp
WHERE calendarid = $calID
GROUP BY DATE(startdate)
ORDER BY DATE(startdate) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting startdate but grouping by `DATE(startdate)`

If the field startdate is datetime and you want to group by date only then you should select a data and group by a date.

Try changing your query to this

```
         SELECT DATE(startdate) AS startdate, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(summary separator '<br />') as summary, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(TIME(startdate)) AS starttime, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(TIME(enddate)) AS endtime
         FROM oc_clndr_objects
         WHERE calendarid = $calID
         GROUP BY DATE(startdate)
         ORDER BY startdate ASC
```

I hope `$calID` is clean variable otherwise your code is subject to SQL injections

Comment: $calID is purely an int pulled from a previous SQL query. I've not tested your answer (although I will) - it turns out to be an issue with pulling the data from the ownCloud database - repeating events are not shown on the dates they repeat on, just the initial date, therefore not reflected in the Schedule. Otherwise, my existing query is fine.

Comment: Having said that, I have made the suggested change.