# how to achieve concatenation using group by

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Suppose there is a table named 'a' with following data:

```
col1, col2
-----------
1     1
1     2
1     3
2     2
2     3
3     4
```

then to achieve following results:

```
col1, col2
--------------
1     6
2     5
3     4
```

i can run query like :

select col1, sum(col2) from a group by col1.

But suppose my table is:

```
col1, col2
---------
1     a
1     b 
1     c
2     d
2     e
3     f
```

here col2 is of varchar type not of numeric type.

what will be the sql query to give following results???

```
col1,  col2
------------
1     a,b,c
2     d,e
3     f
```

i have tried group by on col1 but how to concatenate values in col2???

the problem is that col2 is of varchar type.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are actually using . . . MySQL or SQL Server.

Comment: i want sql query for both mysql and sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of `MySQL` you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` like this:

```
SELECT 
  col1,
  GROUP_CONCAT(col2) as col2
FROM demo
GROUP BY col1;
```

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be464/2).

In case of `SQL Server` you can use `STUFF` like this:

```
SELECT t1.col1,
    stuff((SELECT ',' + CAST(t2.col2 as VARCHAR(10))
     FROM demo t2 WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1
     FOR xml path('')),1,1,'') col2
FROM demo t1
GROUP BY t1.col1;
```

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/be464/10).

Comment: It is working fine, could you please elaborate the query bit more because it would be then easy for me to understand..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group_concat` function in mysql

```
select 
col1,
group_concat(col2) as col2
from table_name
group by col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example, I ran into a similar issue whilst coding up a schedule (working example: www.oldiesplus.com/schedule/)

Here is the link to my question with answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27047139